# My character wont shoot when I use GML in Gamemaker

Tags: game-maker

So I was trying to make a top down shooter in Gamemaker and I decided to convert it from Drag and Drop to GML.

I was trying to make my character shoot a projectile when I press mouse left button but for some reason I dont know why I cant get it working.

```
    // Shooting
if keyboard_check (vk_space)
    {if (alarm[0] = -1)
    alarm[0] = 2}

if (alarm [0] = 0)
    {instance_create (x,y,obj_bullet)
    instance_create (x,y,obj_gunshell)
    instance_create (x,y,obj_gunfire)
    audio_play_sound (snd_shoot1,1,false)
    audio_play_sound (snd_shoot2,1,false)
    }
```

Its set on vk_space for now but it doesnt work when I change it to mouse_check_button (mb_left)

Comment: Have you tried with `mouse_check_button_pressed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working with `mouse_check_button(mb_left)` is simply because this function checks whether left mouse button is being pressed continuously. You need to check if mouse button is pressed just once per time: use `mouse_check_pressed(mb_left)`, it'll work fine.

Comment: Nope.... doesnt work. I have no idea why!

Comment: The code inside `if (alarm [0] = 0)` should be put inside the appropriate Alarm Event, not in the Step Event. And `keyboard_check()` can be transformed into `keyboard_check_pressed()` in order to trigger the action `alarm[0] = 2` once only instead of continuously.

Comment: I think that was the case... Thank you so much! So does that mean I cant put a single big script with a single event then?

Comment: Of course you can. Game Maker itself deals with events, you just have to tell it what code must be executed for a particular event. Also, it cares about decreasing alarms values automatically for you. Your original code would work if you dealt with the alarm valure yourself, but that's something advanced ;)

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to do something like this?

```
if keyboard_check (vk_space) || mouse_check_button(mb_left) {...}
```

I think this should work just fine. Let me know if it doesn't